# Get the previous Thursday date including today

Tags: php

Get the previous Thursday date including `today`
It mean the result should return the `previous Thursday` but when we are on Thursday we just return the current date of today.

`var_dump((new \DateTime('previous Thursday'))->format('Y-m-d'));` this gonna return `string(10) "2018-07-12"` instead of `string(10) "2018-07-19"` ...

Any idea without making any  `if` condition check ? I want one statement with `new DateTime(something)`.

Comment: Then simply check if today is a Thursday first …?

Comment: Well, `previous Thursday` was the 12th, so, check if today is Thursday first and then output something else

Comment: Write a condition if date matches today, take today date else your date with last thursday

Comment: Thant you for replaying, I don't want to check via some if condition, I'm asking if is it possible with any if condition

Comment: "_I'm asking if is it possible with any if condition_" You mean _without_? Why no if condition?

Comment: Yes without, I mean, thank you , with just one `DateTime('and here write something ')`

Comment: `new \DateTime(date('N') == 4 ? '' : 'previous Thursday'))->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: But why don't you want if condition?

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceCherone good solution (y)

Comment: Still an if statement in there though, just a loophole ;p

Comment: @ahmedbhs. Its strange that shorthand conditions are ok, But if condition is not allowed :-)

Comment: shorthand conditions are ok are a solution, but not the best one, @Lawrence Cherone you can update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @ahmedbhs In code if you have either this or that, you need a condition, so you use an *if* or a *switch*, there is no best, just long and short. its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

GIve a try with below code

```
if(date('D') == 'Thu') { 
   echo date("Y-m-d");
} else {
   echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Thursday'));
}
```

Comment: without if condition